# Only One Mail account can be enabled at a time

Tags: mail.app, email

Every five minutes or so a message appears on my wife's MacAir that says

> Mail Password Required

If you click on Continue, it takes you to Internet Accounts in settings. There I can see two email accounts, iCloud and Hotmail. It is the hotmail account that has the problem, so she types in her password and then another message appears:

> Only one Mail account can be enabled at a time.
>   Enabling the Mail account "hername@hotmail.com" will disable "hername@hotmail.com" on this Mac.

If you click OK, the same Mail Password Required comes up again in a few minutes.

Can anyone offer an explanation? Is there some other account setup somewhere? Is there a separate system in Mail, for instance?

Running 10.11.6.